# How much free space does a Live USB logical partition need to work properly?

Tags: 14.04, partitioning, usb, live-usb, usb-drive

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 on a Live USB with 4GB of persistence using Universal USB Installer on a 32GB USB. I split the USB's partition using MiniTool Partition Wizard obtaining a primary partition for storage and a logical partition for the live USB install.

Right now the logical partition I created is 10GB, I went with a lot more than what the Live USB Install actually is because I was testing if this kind of partitioning could work and I wanted to be safe. Here comes my question:

How much free space does the Live USB partition need to work properly? How much can I shrink the partition?

Answer (score 0):

2.5GB is enough, you can see this when you boot from an actual live CD (which can't be increased in size) which can be used at a minimum of 2.5 GB for a DVD and 2GB for a 'CD' so you can go with a minimum of 2.5GB just to be on the safe side.

Comment: Add in the 4G persistence file too, if you're not using a partition for that.